# What does the type { [x: string]: any } mean?

Tags: typescript

I read this [article](https://dev.to/aexol/typescript-tutorial-infer-keyword-2cn) and I cannot understand the signature:

```js
type FuncWithOneObjectArgument<P extends { [x: string]: any }, R> = (props: P) => R;
```

What does `{ [x: string]: any}` mean? I supposed it's a dictionary with values of `any` type and keys of... what? List? Of strings?! What does `x` mean? I tried to remove `x` but it leads to syntax error... How to read the type?

Comment: Oh, God... so it's an object with index method getting `string` and returning `any`?

Comment: it's an object which has string *properties* and the value of each property is of type `any`. For example `{"name": "Alice", "age": 42, "boss": {"name": "Bob"}}`

Comment: More on index types in the TS documentation: [interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), [advanced types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It define what the keys of your object can be. In your case, your keys can only be of type `string`. And your values can be whatever.

The reason behind this is that, in typescript, you can define an object to have certain property :

```
type obj = {property1: string, property2: any};
```

This create an type of object what **MUST** have both property to be valid.

Because of that, there is not intuitive way to define key type.
Hense why we use the square bracket.

```
type obj = {[keys: string]: any};
```

For type like `string` and `int` it seams to be pointless, but you could use the union type operator to define what your keys can be :

```
type obj = {[keys in 'key1'|'key2'|'key3']: any};
```

This synthax is saying that your keys can only be `key1`, `key2` or `key3`.

Comment: So why I cannot write just `{ string: any }` ? Why I need `[`, `]` brackets and this `x`?

Comment: Because, you are not setting the values of your keys, you are defining an object that would have the property `string`.

Comment: `type obj = {[keys: 'key1'|'key2'|'key3']: any};` is invalid in at least TypeScript v3.6.3. Correct way to define a mapped type is `type obj = { [keys in 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3']: any; };`

Comment: Is there solution to avoid any or unknown? It's important in case of destructing it. Any hints?

Comment: @KamilMastalerz If you know the type of the keys in your object, you can use that instead of `any`. `type obj = {[key: string]: string}`.