# Properly typed withRouter - React router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am trying to upgrade to react-router-v6 and I have a lot of class components which I do not want to convert to functional. I found a function from react-router which lets me use withRouter with class components however its not typed. Can someone help me out with this?

Source: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it

This is what I have:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component: any) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: any) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you host minimal working example on codesandbox?

Comment: I do not have a working sample yet. this code is from react-router docs. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job, here is [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-murdock-54gp4l).

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

type IComponentWithRouterProp = {
  [x: string]: any;
};

export function withRouter(Component: Function): Function {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(
    props: IComponentWithRouterProp
  ): JSX.Element {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

Comment: Can we introduce the exact types? any seems like a bad idea here. What say? P.S: Please dont get offended, just learning.

Comment: @a2441918 no offence at all! `[x: string]: any` is a correct way though, you can read on why exactly here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214429/7384132

Comment: So will intellisense be able to identify location.pathname?

Comment: it should not complain at all @a2441918